# seaborn/Matplotlib export EPS causes "falling back to Agg renderer"

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Consider the MWE below. This will cause (Seaborn 0.7.1, Matplotlib 1.5.1):

> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py:222:
>   UserWarning: tight_layout : falling back to Agg renderer
>   warnings.warn("tight_layout : falling back to Agg renderer")

How to fix  this?

**MWE**

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('ps')
import pandas as pd
import random
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ds = pd.DataFrame()
ds['x'] = random.sample(range(1, 100), 25)
ds['y'] = random.sample(range(1, 100), 25)
p = sns.jointplot(x = ds['x'],y = ds['y'],linewidth=1,edgecolor='black',alpha=0.3,stat_func=None)
plt.savefig("test.eps")
```